# Edit terminal documents on third party coding application

Tags: python, terminal, sublimetext

I connect to my Raspberry Pi through SSH on terminal (Mac), and it is a little tedious editing code there, because I cannot click on the line I'd like to edit, but rather I have to scroll and use arrow keys to reach the intended location. Therefore, I usually edit large amounts in Sublime text, and I copy and paste the contents of the file into terminal when I want to run it.

Is it possible to have a direct link between my Raspberry Pi files and Sublime text? (or any other form of editing program). I much prefer the interface for coding than terminal.

Thank you.

Comment: You can mount an SSH filesystem and edit using any editor

Comment: How so? Plugins? @cricket_007

Comment: You could pay $30 for an SSH editor plugin in sublime, sure.

Comment: I grabbed the trial of the SFTP plugin. What directory do I set if I want it to send the files to my raspberry Pi? @cricket_007

Comment: Never used it. Dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at `sshfs`.  It allows mounting a remote directory into your local file system.  You only need to have `ssh` access to the remote host and your local host needs to have FUSE capabilities (most current Linuxes have).